# How to prevent in-line list from wrapping

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to have a navigation menu that stretches 100% across the page wrapper. In my testing with 5 list items, I have the following problems

- With 5 items I was trying to set the width of the items to 20% but that always wraps (see http://jsfiddle.net/L7JGg/6/)
- Setting width to 19.8%, I can get the items to to not wrap, but only at full screen. If I resize, it starts to wrap once I resize the screen (see http://jsfiddle.net/smBvM/1/)

Here is an example with it not wrapping at fullscreen.

[image]

Once you resize the browser, it wraps

[image]

Can someone explain WHY this happens and how to properly fix it?

The jsFiddle links above have code demonstrating the issue live and here is the code.

**CSS**

```
ul.nice-menu, ul.nice-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#zone-menu ul > li {
    width: 19.8%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.nice-menu li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.nice-menu-down li {

}

ul.nice-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #eee;
    position: relative;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="zone-menu">
    <ul class="nice-menu nice-menu-down">
        <li><a href="/">Another Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Another Test2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Menu Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Test3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting this is because each `li` is 20% wide + 1 px on each side for the border.  You can fix this with a negative margin to compensate.

Add `margin: 0 -1px;` to the css selector `ul.nice-menu li`

Answer (score 7):

#### Lame solution

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` for the `<li>`.  This will allow them to respect `white-space: nowrap` from the parent and keep them in line regardless of width.  This also requires that you deal with the whitespace between the `<li>` elements or else it will add space between them.

http://jsfiddle.net/L7JGg/3/

#### Cool solution

Use `box-sizing: border-box` on the `<li>`s.  The 20% width does not include the border with the default `box-sizing: content-box`.  Or I guess you could just remove the border...

http://jsfiddle.net/L7JGg/4/

Comment: box-sizing is a great solution to the border-box issue.

Comment: The Lame solution works fine, however the Cool solution wraps on Chrome, FF & IE latest versions.

Answer (score 3):

## Flexbox solution

Thanks to CSS flex this sort of problem has become rather trivial. One nice thing about this is that the a-tag elements remain equal heights even if one has wrapping content.

Add [vendor prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) as required.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

li:not(:first-child) {
  border-left-width: 0;
}

a {
  flex-grow: 1;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #72c2cc;
}

a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding-left: 0;">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3 wraps first</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're really aiming for, But if you want a specific line to wrap try this.
To prevent all the `<li>` tags from wrapping you can use the float property like so:

```css
ul.nice-menu, ul.nice-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

and then there's right …